# Flat base change and the quasicoherator

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Flat base change seems to always be stated with a quasicompact, quasiseparated hypothesis--this is needed so that the pushforward of a quasicoherent sheaf is quasicoherent. However, we can remove this hypothesis if we use the quasicoherator.

Specifically, let $f : X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $f_* : \operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_X) \to \operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_S)$ be the usual pushforward.

There is a functor $f_{\#} : \operatorname{Qcoh}(X) \to \operatorname{Qcoh}(S)$ which sends $\mathcal{F}$ to the quasicoherator applied to $f_*(\mathcal{F}).$ (See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08D6 for additional information about this coherator.)

Suppose that $j : U \to S$ is an open immersion. Is it true that in the Cartesian diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
f^{-1}(U) @>>j'> X \\
@VVf'V @VVfV \\
U @>>j> S,
\end{CD}$$
we have the analogue of flat base change -- that the natural map $j^*f_{\#} \to f'_{\#}(j')^*$ is an isomorphism?

I'm also interested if flat base change holds for any flat base change with the quasicoherator, but I'm more skeptical of that -- to be honest, I even am skeptical that this statement holds! Does anyone know of a relevant reference, a proof, or a counterexample?

Comment: Since pushforward is compatible with open inclusions (by definition), you are really asking whether the coherator is compatible with open inclusions.  This is directly addressed in B.13 of Appendix B of Thomason-Trobaugh, right after Thomason introduces the coherator.

Comment: @JasonStarr Sorry, I tried looking at this, but I'm not sure it can get me what I want -- B.14 seems to address this, but only in the quasicompact quasiseparated case; although maybe I am missing something.